# What radio frequencies were used by the Soviet space program circa 1961? ("Lost Cosmonaut" recording)

Tags: history, radio-communication, soviet-union, vostok-program

The recent Joe Scott video [The Mysterious "Lost Cosmonaut" Recording | Random Thursday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZidFWLrLnU) describes radio recording said to have been made by the [Judica Cordiglia brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judica-Cordiglia_brothers) from Italy in the early 1960's.

At `04:09` he plays a recording supposedly from February 1961, and at `05:02` he plays "the most mysterious one by far" said to be recorded in May of 1961.

My question is not as much about the veracity of the recordings as it is the nature of the transmissions used by the Soviets circa 1961 and the reception equipment used by the Judica Cordiglia brothers.

What frequencies were likely used by the Soviet space program for communications between spacecraft and Earth circa 1961? Were they say above 50 or 100 MHz and probably required line-of-sight for reception in Italy, or were they substantially lower so that some combination of reflections and refraction could bring over-the-horizon signals to their antennas in Italy?

Text below the not necessarily technically correct, dramatic "reenactment" [Kosmonauta](https://vimeo.com/106216724) says **1962**.

[image]

Comment: Great minds think alike; we each posted questions about Soviet spacecraft communication within minutes of each other.

Comment: different but related: [Is there any truth to the claims of cosmonauts lost in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6516/12102)

Comment: @DrSheldon but I can't find it now; should it also be linked [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48050/12102)?